# Cannot get HTMLUnit to follow links on page that uses a __doPostBack() function

Tags: java, asp.net, postback, htmlunit

I'm trying to scrape data from an ASP page that uses a __doPostBack function when one clicks links.  When I click() the links with HTMLUnit, it returns the page from which I started.  What do I need to do to get it to complete the postback and return the next page?

Code:

```
import java.util.List;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.ScriptResult;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;

public class ScrapperApp {

    private static void go() throws Exception {
        /* turn off annoying htmlunit warnings */
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);

        HtmlPage nextPage;
        ScriptResult onClick; 

        String url = "http://media.ethics.ga.gov/search/Campaign/Campaign_Name.aspx?NameID=5751&FilerID=C2009000085&Type=candidate";

        final WebClient webclient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME_16);
        final HtmlPage page = webclient.getPage(url);

        System.out.println("PULLING LINKS:");

        List<HtmlAnchor> articles = (List<HtmlAnchor>) page.getByXPath("//table[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Name_Reports1_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_dgReports']/tbody/tr/td/a[@class='lblentrylink']");

        for(int x=0; x<articles.size(); x++) {
            System.out.println("Clicking "+x+": "+articles.get(x).asText()); 
            nextPage = articles.get(x).click();
            System.out.println(nextPage.getUrl());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        go();
        System.out.println("COMPLETE");
    }

}
```

Output:

```
PULLING LINKS:
Clicking 0: 
http://media.ethics.ga.gov/search/Campaign/Campaign_Name.aspx?NameID=5751&FilerID=C2009000085&Type=candidate
Clicking 1: 
http://media.ethics.ga.gov/search/Campaign/Campaign_Name.aspx?NameID=5751&FilerID=C2009000085&Type=candidate
...
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't loop on these links, as the same way you cant force them to open in a new window in your browser.

**You need to go back to the "url" page for each click.**

Futhermore, some tweaks needs to be done to htmlunit to make it work properly, here's my working code.

```
    webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_24);
    webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(120000);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(60000);
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.setAjaxController(new NicelyResynchronizingAjaxController());

    String url = "http://media.ethics.ga.gov/search/Campaign/Campaign_Name.aspx?NameID=5751&FilerID=C2009000085&Type=candidate";

    HtmlPage rootPage = webClient.getPage(url);

    List<String> texts = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (HtmlAnchor a : (List<HtmlAnchor>) rootPage.getByXPath("//table[@id='ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_Name_Reports1_TabContainer1_TabPanel1_dgReports']/tbody/tr/td/a[@class='lblentrylink']")) {
        rootPage = webClient.getPage(url);
        HtmlPage page = a.click();
        String text = page.asText();

        if (!texts.contains(text)) {
            System.out.println(page.getUrl());
            texts.add(text);
        } else {
            System.out.println("already seen");
        }
    }
    for (String s : texts) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I did not realize one could suppress the JavaScript errors/exceptions.